# sed add a line after match that contains a new line

Tags: linux, sed

I have the following block.

```
  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
  }

  location /oauth2 {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
  }

  location /login {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
  }
```

I want to add a new line after the proxy_pass but only in the /api section:

```
  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_send_timeout 300;
  }

  location /oauth2 {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
  }

  location /login {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
  }
```

I'm having a tough time getting the regex right.

Semi successful tries:

```
sed -re '/[[:space:]]proxy_pass http:\/\/localhost:8080;/a\    proxy_read_timeout 300;' nginx.con
```

^^^ This adds read_timeout to every line containing the proxy_pass directive obviously, so i tried adding variations of \r or \n or \r\n or [[:space:]]+ to the beginning -  without any luck.

Have tried going the other way with something like:

```
sed '/location \/api {\n\s+proxy_pass.*/a            proxy_read_timeout 300' nginx.conf
```

but failing there too

Can anyone lend a helpful tip?

Answer (score 0):

Challenge accepted.

Try this command:

```
sed 'N;/location \/api.*proxy_pass http:\/\/localhost:8080;/a \    proxy_read_timeout 300;\n    proxy_connect_timeout 300;\n    proxy_send_timeout 300;\n' nginx.conf
```

The magical keywords are:

- the 'N' at the beginning of your sed request, which tells sed to match multiple lines.
- the '/a' which tells sed to add a new line after your match.

And moreover adding proper spaces to match your indentation :)

EDIT: Second suggestion.

```
sed 'N;/location \/api.*proxy.*$/a \    proxy_read_timeout 300;\n    proxy_connect_timeout 300;\n    proxy_send_timeout 300;\n' nginx
```

Comment: Tried it. To keep it simpler:  `sed 'N;/location \/api.*/a \  testreplace' nginx.conf` works; `sed 'N;/location \/api.*proxy/a \  testreplace' nginx.conf` does not. ie: just adding proxy after the .*

Comment: So I'm reading its hard to get sed to read across multiple lines. So I'm trying awk but running into the same type of issue:
`awk '1; /location \/api {/{print "test-replace"}' nginx.conf` is my current iteration

Comment: hello. It's because your match string shall match the entire line. What you did, make it match the entire rest of the file. Look at my answer update for a second suggestion

Comment: still a no go unfortunately. soon as I take out the "proxy" part from your second suggestion, it works. but places it before proxy_pass.